# How to recognize UIView is being removed, or another is coming?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a download screen, and i want to warn the user while exiting or changing the view.

I could not find a proper way for it?

How to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: You may try to call viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear methods...

Comment: Before coming to view, "viewWillAppear" method will fire when another view is coming you can call this method and before moving to another view "viewWillDisappear" methods will fire so you can use that method after view moved. and also you have viewDidDisappear and viewDidappear methods.

Comment: it does not work for uiview, i need a method for uiview not uiviewcontroller

Comment: did u take subview in the same view controller?

Comment: You only adding or removing the subview. so before removing you can try to call an alert. In that alert button action you can remove the view. same as adding also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

this method indicate which view will apeared in currnt view.

```
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

This method indicate that view will remove.

Comment: let me clearify something, i have a uiviewcontroller, and adding screens onto it. do i need to use viewwillappear or disappear method in my removing view or in the main view

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated   write in this..

Answer (score 0):

You can check using methods
**viewDidDisappear:**
It notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view hierarchy.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with dismissing or hiding the view. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

and 
**viewWillAppear:**
It notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This method is called before the receiver’s view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view. You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view.

Answer (score 0):

We can have different method like

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 - (void)viewDidappear:(BOOL)animated
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

Any method you can override. We can use these methods before/after comming/moving to view.

Answer (score 0):

View controllers have some methods when a view will be animated off that have already been mentioned. However it seems like you want the user to confirm the navigation before the screen is animated, not post an alert after the user has already animated from the view.

I recommend you create a custom cancel or back button that handles when a user attempts to  exit the view controller. Before the view is animated off show a UIAlert and ask the user to confirm or Cancel the action. Then navigate away or stay on the current view if the user cancels

Answer (score 0):

viewWillDisappear seems to be the right method to override - give the user the chance to do something BEFORE the view goes away. However, I don't think you can stop the view from going away, as the documentation for viewwillDisappear states that you must call super.viewWillDisappear in your implementation.

Comment: i tried but it is never fired

Comment: Have you tried adding an NSLog message in your viewWillDisappear to check if it's being called or not?